# Yii access a property through multiple levels of BELONGS_TO relations

Tags: php, yii

I have `A` belongs to `B` and `B` belongs to `C`. Suppose `C` has a `property`, and I want to find all `A` such that their `C.property` value is `$myVar`.

What I would like to do is something like

```
A::model()->with('B.C')->findAllByAttributes(array('C.property'=>$myVar))
```

Whenever I do this, however:

```
$brands = FPfdPetItemBrand::model()->with('mImportOperation.mImport')->findAllByAttributes(array('mImport.m_import_id'=>$latestImport->m_import_id));
```

Yii is unhappy:

> CDbException
>
> Table "f_pfd_pet_item_brand" does not have a column named
>   "mImport.m_import_id".

I've been able to achieve what I want by `JOIN`ing, but is there any cleaner way to do this (similar to the one I have tried to use)?

Comment: Try `with('mImportOperation','mImportOperation.mImport')->together(true)` and `findAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use `findAllByAttributes()` to find based on a related attribute. Try `findAll()` instead

```
$brands = FPfdPetItemBrand::model()->with('mImportOperation.mImport')->findAll('mImport.m_import_id=:import_id',array(':import_id'=>$latestImport->m_import_id));
```

(I havnt tested the above. but it should work)